# Jquery passing data to ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, json

I'm having problems passing data values to the Jquery Ajax function.

I have been using the getJSON function and that was working fine but now I want to use the ajax function and I can't work out how to pass in values.

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../../../WebServices/ImageLibrary.svc/getimagesinfolder',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "{ 'id', '2' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data)
            {
                alert('hello');
            }
        });
```

Is this right? Can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: your data segment looks wrong, it should be key:value e.g. {"id":"1"}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have invalid JSON:

```
"{ 'id', '2' }"
```

I would recommend you calling it like this as it will take care of properly encoding your parameters:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../../../WebServices/ImageLibrary.svc/getimagesinfolder',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: '2' }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        alert('hello');
    }
});
```

Comment: It's still not working for me here.  In the operation contract i'm defining it like so.     [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(
        UriTemplate = "getimagesinfolder/{id}",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void GetImagesInFolder(string id);

Comment: So you should pass the id in the url and not use any JSON: `WebServices/ImageLibrary.svc/getimagesinfolder/2`.

Comment: @codemonkey, you should be a little more precise in your comments when talking about *not working*. What does not working mean? To me nothing. Do you get an exception? A wrong value? An unexpected result? A blue screen of death?

Comment: I have put in a success function so if it works it will call up the alert function but it displays nothing. I will try a method without a value and see if that works.

Comment: @codemonkey, is the web service method hit? What does FireBug tells you about the request?

Comment: Got it to work! I set the type to GET and just passed in the value into the url like you said. Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 3):

Use this: `data: { 'id': '2' },`