# Simple jQuery / Ajax error

Tags: ajax, jquery, error-handling

I have this code:

```
var custID = 1;

$.ajax({
    url: 'php/viewCustomer.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: '{custID: ' + custID + '}',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#display').append('<div id="loader"> Lodaing ... </div>');
    },
    complete: function () {
        $('#loader').remove();
    },
    success: function (data) {
        //do something
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('could not process');
    }
});
```

there is an error and alerts the error message `could not process`, so I tried to debug it like this:

```
var custID = 1;

$.ajax({
    url: 'php/viewCustomer.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: '{custID: ' + custID + '}',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#display').append('<div id="loader"> Lodaing ... </div>');
    },
    complete: function () {
        $('#loader').remove();
    },
    success: function (data) {
        //do something
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        alert('Error: ' + jqXHR.status + jqXHR.statusText);
    }
});
```

which outputs:

```
200 OK
```

so if it is ok, why on earth is it executing the error: function. Confused, please help.

Comment: I believe you can edit it, if it bothers you so much

Comment: My point is edit, the OP will see you're edit and understand he's awful at fishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data string is incorrectly formatted, if you are intending it to be a JSON object. There was a previous question about this: [Jquery passing data to ajax function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866150/jquery-passing-data-to-ajax-function)

Instead, try:

```
data: JSON.stringify({custID: custID}),
```

The format is (key):(variable). My previous answer have placed quotes around the variable, which is not necessary.

Comment: My bad. I have changed my answer.

Comment: Ive sorted the error out on my own. I am a beginner in jQuery. My php file was not echoing out any json.

Comment: Aha, that, too. Always remember to check what the PHP script echoes out ;) Been there done that, so you're not alone.

Comment: Thank so much, your so kind, Ive selected your answer because you've tried your best to help me. And your info will be useful in the future.